# ¿Como almacenar huella dactilar?

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo un proyecto para almacenar el registro de las huellas dactilares de los trabajadores de ingreso en la empresa. Estoy usando para ello la librería **ZKFPEngX**. Les dejo con el código:

```
private void cbox_D0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
       ZKFPEngX sensor = new ZKFPEngX();

        if (cbox_D0.Checked)
        {
            sensor.SensorIndex = 0;
            sensor.InitEngine();
            if (sensor.Active)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sensor activo");
                sensor.OnCapture += X_OnCapture;
            }
        ...
    }
```

El sensor está activado porque me muestra dicho mensaje, ahora debería entrar al evento *X_OnCapture* en el cual muestro un mensaje. Les dejo el código:

```
private void X_OnCapture(bool ActionResult, object ATemplate)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Dedo identificado");
    }
```

Al debuggear nunca entra a este evento y por supuesto no muestra el mensaje. Probé con el evento *OnEnroll* y tampoco accede al mismo. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Pero es un desarrollo web, eso no funciona. Los eventos se dan en el servidor no en el cliente. Si fuera una integracion con una lectora deberia darse co cdigo javascript que actue en el browser y dspues este realizar el submit al servidor para que ingrese al evento

Comment: de verdad un `MessageBox.Show()` en un desarrollo asp.net ? sabes que eso no se puede realizar porque el mensaje se visualiza en el servidor dejando el thread freezado, creo que deberias leer algo mas sobre desarrollo web porque estas errando en conceptos basicos

Comment: @LeandroTuttini no es un sistema web es una aplicación desktop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Logré resolverlo de esta forma:

```
private void btn_Conectar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sensor.SensorIndex = 0;
        if (sensor.InitEngine() == 0)
        {
            this.btn_Conectar.Enabled = false;
            sensorHandler = sensor.CreateFPCacheDB();
            sensor.OnImageReceived += new IZKFPEngXEvents_OnImageReceivedEventHandler(fp_OnImageReceived);
            sensor.OnCapture += new IZKFPEngXEvents_OnCaptureEventHandler(fp_OnCapture);
        }
    }

private void fp_OnImageReceived(ref bool Image) {
        object imgdata = new object();
        string base64 = sensor.GetTemplateAsString();
        bool flag = sensor.GetFingerImage(ref imgdata);
        if (flag) {
            System.Drawing.ImageConverter converter = new System.Drawing.ImageConverter();
            Image img = (Image)converter.ConvertFrom(imgdata);
            img_Huella.Image = img;
            this.huellaByte = (byte[])imgdata;
            this.huellaImage = img;
        }
    }
    private void fp_OnCapture(bool ActionResult, object ATemplate) {
        if (sensor.LastQuality >= 70)
            this.huella64 = sensor.GetTemplateAsString();
    }
```

Espero ayude a otras personas.